# Nodejs delete all image file which name is X an extension is an image

Tags: node.js, fs

I'd like to delete imagefiles from my storage in nodejs by name and not by extension.
For example: If I've 1.png, i'd like to delete it. And 1.jpg also. How can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your storage is local filesystem, you can use @wrote/read-dir-structure package to get the list of all files recursively:

```
import { unlinkSync } from 'fs'
import readDirStructure, { getFiles } from '@wrote/read-dir-structure'

(async () => {
  const path = 'example/directory'
  const res = await readDirStructure(path)
  const files = getFiles(res.content, path)
  const filtered = files.filter((file) => {
    return file.startsWith(FILE_NAME)
  })
  filtered.forEach((file) => unlinkSync(file))
})()
```